# JasperSoft Studio issues initializing fonts

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

all,
I'm having issues when editing my Jasper report in Jaspersoft Studio, the following exception is shown.

```
Could not initialize class
com.jaspersoft.studio.preferences.fonts.utils.FontUtils
```

In order to cause the error all I have to do is try to edit any text field or static text. 
Below is my report and the fonts.xml in the project's fonts.jar file. The font I'm trying to use is Roboto and is included in the preference section of JasperSoft and I have include al ttf necessary.

This happens on all reports on the project, here a sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.12.2.final using JasperReports Library version 6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Charges" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="98e6c42b-ce3b-4d93-b73d-e17368a5f94a">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="DataAdapterDummyJSON.xml"/>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[data.charges]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="chargeName" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="chargeName"/>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="chargeName"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[chargeName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="chargeAmount" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="chargeAmount"/>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="chargeAmount"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[chargeAmount]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="24">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="70" y="0" width="174" height="20" uuid="0b113029-609b-42fc-8269-384d8af6921d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Roboto" size="15"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{chargeName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="310" y="2" width="132" height="20" uuid="78b92d3d-4a53-4976-a8e8-e0dab507ce6a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Roboto" size="15" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["$"+ new DecimalFormat("0.00").format($F{chargeAmount})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Project's fonts.jar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<fontFamilies>

    <fontFamily name="DejaVu Sans">
        <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
        <!--
        <locales>
            <locale>en_US</locale>
            <locale>de_DE</locale>
        </locales>
        -->
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="DejaVu Serif">
        <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="DejaVu Sans Mono">
        <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

    <!--
        Mapping Java logical fonts, for the sake of HTML export only.
    -->

    <fontFamily name="SansSerif">
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>
    <fontFamily name="Serif">
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>
    <fontFamily name="Monospaced">
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

</fontFamilies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is occurred due to non available Font.
Studio giving me same error. Problem got solved.
I have never get this while working on ireport 5.0 or ireport 5.6 may be because java version which i am using or already some where font path is already configured.
jasper studio windows -> preference -> Jaspser studio -> fonts
Here add the path of fonts i have given "C:/windwos"

or you can also try this below option some will work for you

```
1. Switched from Open JDK to Sun JDK
2. Installed MS Core Fonts
3. Packaged JasperReport font library jar with the application
```

Main cause of problem is occurring due to font